# Error on Windows when installing Node.js via conda package manager

Tags: node.js, anaconda, conda

Has anyone ever seen the following error when trying to install Node.js on Windows via the conda package manager using the command:

```
conda install nodejs
```

This command was issued in the Anaconda Prompt. The download of nodejs worked, then the following error was displayed:

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages
nodejs-10.13.0       | 13.2 MB   | ############################################################################ | 100%

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\Users\\212570025\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\
anaconda3\\pkgs\\nodejs-10.13.0-0\\node_modules\\
npm\\test\\npm_cache\\_cacache\\content-v2\\sha512\\f3\\e8\\
2d6a0b75ad5cebd09177d93f572dbd8b877ee9f1505b2e84e03810fa0412e4904060be7d2a4df4221b1bb92884db886826bf8cd26634667a2d103a999438'
```

Any ideas on how to debug this issue would be sincerely appreciated. I have not encountered it on Windows, macOS or Linux previously and I am trying to help a student.

Comment: I checked [the **win-64** tarball](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/nodejs/10.13.0/download/win-64/nodejs-10.13.0-0.tar.bz2), and that is a legitimate file that should be there in your installation, presumably to verify integrity of the install. First, I'd clear the cached version of this from your `anaconda\pkgs\` directory, just to make sure. Then, try reinstalling but with `conda install nodejs -vv` so you can see debug messages if it fails again. If it does fail, add that info to your question.

Comment: Also, is your user name really `212570025` or did you intentionally obscure it for the post here?  Or is maybe that involved in the error?

Comment: Ugh, looks like I didn't match my code delimiters.  Should be, try installing with `conda install nodejs -vv`

Comment: Thanks merv. The username was from a student who I am trying to help resolve this issue. I went to https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/nodejs and found the following install commands that did work for the student, but it's still unclear why the original command did not work:
 
```
conda install -c conda-forge nodejs 

conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 nodejs 

conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 nodejs 
```

I've never seen the -vv option. Is that nodejs specific?

for some reason I cant get the commands in computer font at the moment.